# Adding a value to a custom Array Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have failed to add the value to the cell, Which is defined as Cell[] cell;
Please help me out it's an open source software am trying to develop.

```
/*
 *Java Code.
 */ 
 int n;
 Cell[] cell;

/* The constructor needs three parameters:
 * l = lower limit of the range of the histogram
 * h = upper limit of the range of the histogram
 * n = number of intervals in this range
 * The range now equals [l,h), where l lies inside the range and h lies outside
 * the range.
 */
public Histogram(double l, double h, int m){
    this.low = l;
    this.high = h-1;
    this.n = m;
    this.width = ((high - low)/n);
    this.cell = new Cell[this.n];
}

/* resets counting: counters for all intervals are reset to zero
 */
public void reset() {
    System.out.println("reset to be implemented") ;
}

/* update(val) updates the histogram with value val. If l <= val < h then
 * the corresponding interval will be increased by one
 */
public void update(double val) {
    System.out.println("update to be implemented") ;
    if(low <= val && val < high) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cell[i] = val;
        }
    }

}

private void printForm(String str, int i) {
    System.out.print(str);
    for (int j = str.length(); j < i; j++) System.out.print(" ");
}

/* a histogram is printed by printing an interval per line. For each
 * interval [a,b) the number of occurances will be displayed using
 * 'x'-characters: as many will be printed as the coresponding counter for
 * this interval
 * On each such line, first the values a and b are printed to denote the
 * range of the interval.
 * <pre>
 * 1    -   3.5 : xxx
 * 3.5  -   -6  : xx
 * 6    -   8.5 : xxxxxxx
 * 8.5  -   11  : xxxxxxxx
 * </pre> 
 * e.g, there where two stored values within teh interval [10.20).
 */
public void print() {
    double curVal = low;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        String str = String.valueOf(curVal);
        this.printForm(str, 8);
        this.printForm("-", 4);
        // System.out.print("-");
        curVal += width;
        str = String.valueOf(curVal);
        this.printForm(str, 8);
        System.out.print(": ");
        System.out.print(cell);
        cell[i].print();
        // System.out.println();
    }
}
}

class Cell {
private int value = 0;

public void print() {
    System.out.println();
    for (int j = 1; j <= value; j++) System.out.print("x");
    System.out.println();
}

public void reset() {
    value = 0;
}

public void plus1() {
    value++;
}
}
```

I have failed to implement the method print in the class Cell.
I'm lost on how to go on about this and I'm trying to crack it but it has failed.
I've tried using push, add and they've both failed and now you are my last hope thank you.
Please anyhelp will be appreciated.

Comment: Why would `print` method be adding to the `cell` array? --- Anyway, I see no attempt to add anywhere in the code.

Comment: "I've tried using push, add and they've both failed..."  -- I don't see where in your code you've tried this.  Please [edit] your question to include your attempt(s) at this implementation, along with how they should work and any error(s)/bad output you're getting.

Comment: `cell[i] = val;`, you are trying to insert a `double` into a Cell[] which of course doesn’t work and will give you a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `update` method to this

```
public void update(int index) {
    System.out.println("update to be implemented") ;
    if(low <= index && index < high) {      
       cell[index].plus1();
    }
}
```

Now the method will increase the value of the Cell object at position `index` in the array with one